# Center align an image within a div with media type in Twitter Bootstrap 3.0

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using Bootstrap 3.0. I have the following 2 column div setup coded as such:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6" id="leftHeader"><a href="#"><img src="image.gif" class="img-responsive" /></a></div>
    <div class="col-md-6" id="rightHeader">TEST2</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

When the browser window is changed to a smaller size or the site is used on a mobile device, I would like the image content in the leftHeader to center in the div and the text in the rightHeader to center in its div, as well. Bootstrap automatically stacks the 2 columns, which is the desired result.

I was able to center the text in the rightHeader with the code below:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 820px) {
    #rightHeader{
    text-align:center;
    }       
}
```

However, I cannot seem to get the leftHeader to center my image. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try this:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 820px) {
  #leftHeader > a > img { margin: auto; }
}
```

**[It's working here](http://jsfiddle.net/5Pt8U/)** (added border in fiddle just to see container).